# Does logical or ignores second statement if first is true

Tags: java, eclipse, logical-or

In Java (Eclipse), when having a statement such as `if (true || false)`, it will end up true but the question is will the compiler evaluate the second statement if the first is true?
This is of an importance to me because I have an operation I need to do if the variable is null OR it has a certain value.
My statement looks like `if (array == null || array[i] < array[j])`.
You can see the reason for my question, because if array is set to null then the second statement will produce an error.
So, will the true from `array == null` suffice or will the compiler evaluate `array[i] < array[j])` also?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No it won't.

- With boolean operator `||`, if first term is `true` second term won't
  be evaluated.
- With bitwise operator `|` both terms are evaluated

Similarly...

- With boolean operator `&&`, if first term is `false` second term won't be evaluated
- With bitwise operator `&`, both terms are evaluated

Java operators docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Comment: Thank you!
I could have tested it on my expression but reaching the point where I could debug it is far away and it would be a shame to do all that work and end up fixing it.

Comment: @SharonJDDorot - have a look at the Groovy Console (http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) - really useful for putting these little snippets in.

Comment: flawless answer @Mena